# what is the maximum Length of Recording Worklight Mobile Testing?

Tags: automated-tests, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

First thing is probably to install this mobile testing capability in Worklight Studio. If you have installed the Worklight developer edition in the past, you are familiar with installing Worklight Studio from the Eclipse Market place. This is also the place where you can find the IBM Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight (the official name of the mobile testing feature in Worklight)

If you use the Eclipse Help/Eclipse Marketplace menu and search for Worklight, you will find the Worklight Studio developer edition and the mobile testing component.

Answer (score 0):

MTW does not impose any such limitation.  The only limit is the memory and disk of your mobile device.